# Serial to HID keyboard device converter

Tags: usb, keyboard, serial, hid

I am working on a project to collect data from a barcode scanner using an arduino which in turn is connected to a POS/laptop. So far i am able to collect the data from the barcode scanner by using the arduino as a host and in order to send the scanner data from the arduino to the laptop i am using a basic FTDI board (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9716) that coverts serial data from the arduino to USB. However, it shows up as a COM port in my computer and i need an additional serial monitor to see the data transferred from the arduino. Is there a device that converts serial data from the arduino to "HID keyboard Device" similar to the FTDI board.

Please let me know if i have not made myself clear or if you need more information.

Comment: Not sure whether this belongs here or on https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for the response, i was not sure where to post it. I will post it over there.